# Progress bar will not display

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just want to add a progress bar to my page and I cannot even get it to display! I stripped the website down to a bare minimum to try to isolate what could but can't figure it out! I was thinking it was my custom css file I created, but I removed it and the issue persisted.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>STEMuli Explore</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <a name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()"><img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="100" height="100" alt="Responsive image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a href="#" name="redirectCreate" onClick="redirectCreate()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
              Create</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <a href="#" name="redirectExplore" onClick="redirectExplore()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
              Explore</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Logical JS files-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the class `row` from the parent div containing the progress bars.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>STEMuli Explore</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
    <a name="redirectHome" onClick="redirectHome()"><img src="/img/logo.png" class="img-fluid" width="100" height="100" alt="Responsive image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-6">
        <a href="#" name="redirectCreate" onClick="redirectCreate()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
            Create</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 text-center">
        <a href="#" name="redirectExplore" onClick="redirectExplore()">
          <h1 class="text-center">
            Explore</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="h-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 50%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 75%" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Logical JS files-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to a misunderstanding of the way the Bootstrap 4 grid system works.

Here's some tips for solving this specific issue, as well as issues in the future.

See the snippet below, which works:

1. May I suggest you [read the Bootstrap 4 grid docs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/), and you'll discover that this is all based on flex, so you either need to remove `.row`, add `.col`, or make other alterations to get the layout you are looking for.
2. In the working snippet below, you'll notice I put "border" styles on the progress bars.  This is a troubleshooting technique that can show you immediately what is going on (when I did with your code, all the progress bars were tiny-narrow, stacked tightly against each other horizontally).
3. In the snippet below, I *dramatically* simplified the code.  This is a practice for isolating the problem - simplify until it's just the one issue / item, solve it, then you can bake that back into your big-picture plan.
4. Leverage the browser's developer tools and inspect the elements.  Doing so reveals *tons* about what is going on.  It's an essential tool in any web developer's toolkit, so learn it, master it.  It is your friend!

```css
.progress {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.progress-bar {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>STEMuli Explore</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div>Borders added to illustrate a troubleshooting technique</div>
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/redirect.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!--Logical JS files-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The containing div class `row h-100` probably expects a blocky content. I am not too familiar with bootstrap4, but in bootstrap3, there is this concept of `col-md-12`... wrap the progress bar by div with class `col-lg` or something?

```
<div class="row h-100 justify-content-center">
  <div class = "col-lg">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

ps `ctrl` `shift` `i` is your friend

Comment: Bootstrap 4 uses flex instead of floats / percentage widths.  You're on the right track, but it has to include the base class `col` as well, and instead of `col-lg`, `col-lg-1` (for example).